# Spring boot can't find the appropriate URL mapping after adding another spring MVC project as a dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a spring boot project which takes service from another spring mvc project. Before I add the service project, URL mapping works perfectly for the spring boot project. But after adding the spring MVC project as a dependency and scanning all the components and mappers, that project can't determine the URL mapping. (two projects have no any compile error)

This is my controller for spring boot project

```
@Controller
public class PriceFactorController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PriceFactorController.class);


/*

  @Autowired
    PriceAggregator2 priceAggregator2;
*/

    @GetMapping("/price")
    public ModelAndView priceGet() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        PriceSearch priceSearch = new PriceSearch();
        modelAndView.addObject("priceSearch", priceSearch);
        modelAndView.setViewName("price");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @PostMapping("/price")
    public ModelAndView pricePost(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("priceSearch") PriceSearch priceSearch,
            BindingResult bindingResult,
            Model model) {

        priceSearch.makeDestinationList();
        priceSearch.makeTravellerList();

        //  List<PricingResult> resultSet=priceAggregator2.getPriceResultList(priceSearch.getPriceSearchDTO());

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        logger.debug(priceSearch.toString());
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            modelAndView.setViewName("price");
        } else {
            modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/result");
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }


    @GetMapping("/result")
    public ModelAndView priceResult(
            @RequestParam(value = "key", required = false) String key,
            Model model) {
        Result result = new Result();
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("result", result);
        modelAndView.setViewName("result");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seems to look for this controller,
Here are my logs..

```
2018-05-28 16:42:15.114 DEBUG 27866 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/price]
2018-05-28 16:42:15.115 DEBUG 27866 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /price
2018-05-28 16:42:15.115 DEBUG 27866 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/price]
2018-05-28 16:42:15.115 DEBUG 27866 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/price] are [/**]
2018-05-28 16:42:15.115 DEBUG 27866 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/price] are {}
2018-05-28 16:42:15.115 DEBUG 27866 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/price] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@45cc601]]] and 1 interceptor
2018-05-28 16:42:15.115 DEBUG 27866 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/price] is: -1
2018-05-28 16:42:15.116 DEBUG 27866 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2018-05-28 16:42:15.116 DEBUG 27866 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2018-05-28 16:42:15.116 DEBUG 27866 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2018-05-28 16:42:15.116 DEBUG 27866 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2018-05-28 16:42:15.117 DEBUG 27866 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]
2018-05-28 16:42:15.117 DEBUG 27866 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
2018-05-28 16:42:15.131 DEBUG 27866 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, text/html;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [text/html])
2018-05-28 16:42:15.134 DEBUG 27866 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView   : No FreeMarker view found for URL: error.ftl
2018-05-28 16:42:15.134 DEBUG 27866 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@7be99ccd] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2018-05-28 16:42:15.134 DEBUG 27866 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@7be99ccd] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-05-28 16:42:15.134 DEBUG 27866 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

Additionally,

```
package lk.xxc;

import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

//http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html'
@MapperScan("com.xxc")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xxc"})
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class SpringBootWebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

---

This is the dependency I added

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxc</groupId>
            <artifactId>price-engine</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: how did you add the other project as dependency?

Comment: I just added the <groupId>,<artifactId>,</version> to pom.xml as a dependency. And I added following lines above the main class of the springBoot project.@MapperScan("com.xxc")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xxc"})
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })

Comment: Does both of your project have the same groupId?

Comment: No those group id are deferent. Spring boot as lk.xxc   and Spring mvc project has com.xxc

Comment: Add your main class and the groupId of both the projects to the question

Comment: I added main class and the dependecy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to add the base packages for both projects.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xxc", "lk.xcc"})
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class SpringBootWebApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

This will scan components in both `com.xxc` and `lk.xcc`

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `@RequestMapping`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/price-factor")
public class PriceFactorController{
.......
}
```

Comment: I put this    @GetMapping("/price") fro mapping in controller. is that wrong? This is not a rest service

Comment: That's totally depends on your design. It's just my suggestion. When you have two same  '@GetMapping("/price")' in two different classes. You will get issue

Comment: Actually this happens not only the /price. when I put whatever correct url its happen.